# C# Remove a list from a "jagged" list

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to remove a `List<int>` from a `List<List<int>>`, I've looked everywhere and haven't found a solution.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
List<List<int>> my2DList = ... ;  // this is where I assign my 2D list
my2DList.Remove(new List<int>( ... ));
```

But `my2DList`'s length stays the same. What should I do?

Comment: That's not a "2D" list - it's a "jagged" list.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oh alright. Sorry, I'm a beginner in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `List<int>` doesn't override `Equals`/`GetHashCode`, so your new list is never equal to the existing one. (Basically, it will be comparing references rather than contents.)

Three options:

- Find the exact list you want to remove, and pass that reference to `Remove`
- Find the *index* of the list you want to remove, and pass that to `RemoveAt`
- Create a predicate and use `RemoveAll`

An example of the last one:

```
List<int> listToRemove = new List<int> { ... };
my2DList.RemoveAll(x => x.SequenceEqual(listToRemove));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the exact object you want to remove, not a new object (which would be a different object). So for example:

```
my2DList.Remove(my2DList[3]);
```

If you do not know the index, or the object, you'd need to iterate over the List to find the correct object.

Comment: If you know the index then `my2Dlist.RemoveAt(3);` would make more sense.

Comment: Yes, of course. Just wanted to emphasise what i mean.